# Equivalence of Surrogacy and Causal Mediation Assumptions?

Tags: econometrics, causality, treatment-effect, surrogate

I am interested in characterizing the statistical surrogacy condition $Y \perp W | S$ as per the setup in: https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.09326.

Suppose $Y_{i} \in \mathbb{R}$ is the outcome of interest, a surrogate vector $S_{i} \in \mathbb{R}^{K}$ and binary treatment $W_{i} \in \{0,1\}$. Using potential outcomes notation, suppose further that we have exclusion $Y_{i} = Y_{i}(W_{i}, S_{i}) = Y_{i}(S_{i})$ such that the only causal effect of $W \to Y$ operates through $W\to S \to Y$. We write in potential outcomes notation $S_{i}=S_{i}(W_{i})$ to indicate the causal link $W \to S$.

In appendix (A) of the above paper, the authors show that given exclusion and unconfounded assignment of $W_{i}$, sequential unconfoundedness: $$S_{i} \perp Y(s) | W_{i}$$
implies surrogacy: $Y_{i} \perp W_{i} | S_{i}$. This proof is immediate from an application of the graphoid axioms.

**Question**: Is the converse true: supposing exclusion and unconfounded assignment of $W_{i}$, together with surrogacy, can we conclude $S_{i} \perp Y(s) | W_{i}$?

**Motivation** It seems to be a "folk theorem" in the surrogates literature that the surrogacy condition implies at least the absence of confounders between $S,Y$ and given this proof it seems there could be an equivalence to characterize the statistical surrogacy condition, which would be helpful for interpretation and practical consideration of how realistic the condition is.

**What I've Tried** For the constant treatment effects case: $$Y_{i} = f(S_{i}) + U_{i}$$ $$S_{i} = k \times W_{i} + V_{i}$$
where $k \neq 0$ the proof is relatively simple from an application of the graphoid axioms with the definitions, which yields $S \perp U$ and $U \perp V | W$. However, the general case appears to need a different approach since this proof technique relies on the error terms $U,V$ being a fixed random variable and thus doesn't generalize to arbitrary treatment effects heterogeneity.