# Conditional Independence for Surrogacy argument

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, surrogate

Let $Z_1, Z_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfy $\mathbb{E}Z_{1}=\mathbb{E}Z_{2}=0$.

Let $W \in \{0,1\}$ and let $A,B \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfy $\mathbb{E}A \neq \mathbb{E}B$. All of the above are random variables.

Finally, suppose $\mathbb{E}\{WZ_{1} + (1-W)Z_{2}\}| WA+(1-W)B, W\} = \mathbb{E}\{WZ_{1} + (1-W)Z_{2}\}| WA+(1-W)B\} $

i.e. the conditional expectation is free of $W$.

**Question:** Does this setup, or this setup and additional regularity conditions, imply that $\mathbb{E}\{Z_{1}|A\} = \mathbb{E}\{Z_{2}|B\}=0$?

**Partial Answer**: In the case $Z_{1}=Z_{2}=Z$ and $A=B+k$ for a non-random constant $k \in \mathbb{R}$, this is easy to show using the fact that for any function $f$, if $f(x)=f(x+k)$ for all $k \neq 0$ then $f$ is a constant function.

To prove the general case it's escaping me how to handle the case $Z_{1}\neq Z_{2}$ and when the translation between $A,B$ has a random component.

This is a step I'm trying to work out for a continued attempt on the [Equivalence of Surrogacy and Causal Mediation Assumptions?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/623282/equivalence-of-surrogacy-and-causal-mediation-assumptions) proof. Thank you!